# How can I set Gas Price in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, gas-price, internal-transactions

Can I set gas price in internal transactions, of my functions?
For example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

interface Itest {
     function sendToken(address to) external;
}

contract TestContract {

    Itest _Itest;

    constructor(address add) {
        _Itest = Itest(add);
    }

    function sendTokens(address to1, address to2) external {
        _Itest.sendToken(to1);
        _Itest.sendToken(to2);
}
    
}
```

I call function sendTokens(address to1, address to2), which sent tokens on two addresses, with the help of Interface of another contract. I want to manipulate the gas price of this internal transactions.

Can I do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer correctly. Can you tell me what do you meant by manipulating gas prices?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set/update the gas price inside your transaction. The gas price is determined by the one signing and thus initializing the transaction.

Comment: and if I want to swap some tokens in DeFi (uniswap, pancakeswap) from the code in one function, will all of them have one gas price, which I chose in call of function?

Answer (score 0):

The gas price is determined by the market, not by the contract.